# job is failed because can't cd to /home/ubuntu/development: No such file or directory

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

I have two servers:

```
192.168.8.52 //gitlab server
192.168.8.54 //runner is installed and development destination.
```

I used ssh-key to connect from 52 to 54.
in server 52 when I use `ssh ubuntu@192.168.8.54` it login without any password.

this is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  GITLAB_URL: "git@192.168.8.52:****/***.git"

build-job:
  stage: build
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "demo"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "production"'
  script:
    - echo "Hello"
    - echo "build files should biuld here after dockerizing"

test-job:
  stage: test
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "demo"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "production"'
  script:
    - echo "This job will runs tests after adding tests"



.deploy:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: deploy
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  script:
    - cd ${PROJECT_DIR}
    - ssh ubuntu@192.168.8.54 "cp -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR $PROJECT_DIR"   

deploy-staging-job:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    GIT_BRANCH: development
    PROJECT_NAME: "development"
    PROJECT_DIR: "/home/ubuntu/${PROJECT_NAME}"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"'
```

but I got this error:

```
$ cd ${PROJECT_DIR}
+ echo '$ cd ${PROJECT_DIR}'
+ cd /home/ubuntu/development
/bin/sh: cd: line 130: can't cd to /home/ubuntu/development: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2
```

I created this path on 54:

```
/home/ubuntu/development
```